# The space of separately continuous bilinear forms is Hausdorff

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$, $F$, $G$ be locally convex topological vector spaces. Let $\mathcal{G}$ (resp. $\mathcal{H}$) be a family of bounded subsets of $E$ (resp. $F$). The $\mathcal{G}$-$\mathcal{H}$-topology on the space of separately continuous bilinear forms on $E \times F$ into $G$, $\mathscr{B}(E,\,F;\,G)$, is the topology of uniform convergence on the products $G \times H$ of $\mathcal {G} \times \mathcal {H}$.

A remark in the book says, that $\mathscr{B}(E,\,F;\,G)$ provided with such topology is Hausdorff, if $G$ is Hausdorff and if $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are total families (families whose union is a total subset of $E$ resp. $F$). A subset is total, if its linear hull is dense.

We denote by $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ the  space of separately continuous bilinear forms on weak duals of $E$ and $F$ into $\mathbb{C}$, with the $\mathcal{G}$-$\mathcal{H}$-topology, where $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are taken to be the families of all equicontinuous subsets of $E'$ and $F'$ respectively.

In my opinion, $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ has to be Hausdorff, since $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff and the union of all equicontinuous subsets of $E'$ is $E'$ (the same holds for $F$).

But another book says, that the space $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is Hausdorff if and only if both $E$ and $F$ are Hausdorff.

My question is: under which conditions is the space $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ Hausdorff.

EDIT:

The basis of neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is defined by taking the sets
$$ \mathcal{U}(A',\, B',\, V) = \{ \Phi \in \mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma}) \colon \Phi(A',\, B') \subseteq V \big\}$$
where $A'$ (resp. $B'$) varies over $\mathcal{G}$ (resp. $\mathcal{H}$) and $V$ over a basis of neighborhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Since $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is a topological vector space, if we want to show, that $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is Hausdorff, we have to proof, that for every $\Phi \in \mathscr{B}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$, such that $\Phi \neq 0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $\mathscr{B}_{\varepsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ such that $\Phi \notin U$.

Let $\Phi \in \mathscr{B}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ be nonzero. That means that there are $x' \in E'$ and $y' \in F'$ such that $\Phi(x',\, y') \neq 0$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Phi(x',\, y') \notin V$. Hence we have
$$ \Phi \notin \mathcal{U}(x',\, y',\, V)$$
The set $\mathcal{U}(x',\, y',\, V)$ is a neighborhood of zero in $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$. Hence the space $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is Hausdorff.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Which books do you cite? I think that your proof is fine.

Comment: @Jochen I'm working through Trèves „Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels“. By the definition of the $\mathcal{G}$-$\mathcal{H}$-Topology on the space of separately continuous bilinear maps of $E \times F$ into $G$ assumes he, that all three spaces are locally convex and Hausdorff. And as a commentary says he, that the space $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma},\, G)$ is Hausdorff as soon as this is true of $G$. Later in the chapter about topological tensor products defines he the $\epsilon$-topology on a tensor product.

Comment: @Jochen  It’s the topology carried over from $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ when we regard the latter as a vector subspace of $\mathscr{B}_{\epsilon}(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$. Where $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ is a space of continuous bilinear maps of $E'_{\sigma} \times F'_{\sigma}$ into $\mathbb{C}$. He says, that it is obvious, that the $\epsilon$-topology on $E \otimes F$ is Hausdorff if and only if both $E$ and $F$ are Hausdorff.

Comment: @Jochen And I try to understand this conclusion, because Schaefer in “Toplogical Vector Spaces” gives as remark, that $\mathscr{B}(E,\, F,\, G)$ is Hausdorff if $G$ is Hausdorff and this $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ families are total.

Comment: You need Hausdorff spaces in order to have the canonical map $E\otimes F \to B(E'_\sigma,F'_\sigma)$ *injective* -- to see what happens look at the extreme cases where $E$ and $F$ carry the coarsest locally convex topology.

Comment: @Jochen What exactly do you mean by the canonical map from $E \otimes F$ into $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$? Trèves defines $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ as a tensor product of $E$ and $F$.

Comment: $e \otimes f (\eta, \phi)= \eta(e) \phi(f)$

Comment: @Jochen Sorry, but I really don't understand, what does it mean...

Comment: For elementary tensors you define  the canonical map.by the formula given in the previous comment and then you extend linearly.

Comment: @Jochen Wait, do you mean the map $E \times F \to B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$  with $(e,\, f) \mapsto e \otimes f \colon (\eta,\, \phi) \mapsto \eta(e) \, \phi(f)$?

Comment: Right. Sorry I ca only use my mobile phone right now and it's neither easy to read nor to write.

Comment: I can’t see, why the map isn’t injective, if $E$ and $F$ aren’t Hausdorff. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Of $E$ has the coarsest topology then $E'$ only contains the functional $0$.

Comment: Oh, right, the trivial topology is locally convex... But I'm a little bit confused now. If $E$ and $F$ are not Hausdorff and the canonical map isn’t injective, we can’t identify a tensor product of $E$ and $F$ with $B(E’_{\sigma},\, F’_{\sigma})$, right? But this art of topology on the tensor product is defined for all locally convex spaces, and for not Hausdorff spaces too, how does it work?

Comment: You can nevertheless take the initial topology w.r.t. the canonical map.

Comment: How do you mean that? The space $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ depends on the originally topology of $E$ and $F$, we can’t just “change” them. Or maybe I don’t really understand, what was you suggestion. I’m really sorry to bother you.

Comment: Let us call the canonical map $J: E\otimes F\to B(E'_\sigma,F'_\sigma)$ and endow the latter space with a locally convex topology (e.g., uniform convergence on products of equicontinuous sets). The initial topology on $E\otimes F$ is the coarsest locally convex topology making $J$ continuous. It is induced by the seminorm system $\lbrace p\circ J: p$ continuous seminorm on $B(E'_\sigma,F'_\sigma)\rbrace$.

Comment: This time you really mean the map from tensor product into the space of continuous bilinear forms, right? But if $E$ and $F$ are originally regarded with trivially topologies, the space $B(E'_{\sigma},\, F'_{\sigma})$ contains only zero, since $E'$ and $F’$ contain only zero functionals.

Comment: Then $J$ is the zero map whose initial topology is again the coarsest topology. -- We should stop this extended discussion in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55405/discussion-between-imperio-and-jochen).